# Migrating a site: ereg to pregmatch?

Tags: php, preg-match, ereg

I'm in the process of migrating a horrible drupal site to a new server - a server with a newer version of PHP. Checking the site I get the following error:

**Deprecated: Function ereg() is deprecated in /var/sites/n/nanohex.org/public_html/includes/file.inc on line 902**

Line 902 looks like the following:

```
elseif ($depth >= $min_depth && ereg($mask, $file)) {
```

My understanding is that ereg is no longer used and I need to replace with pregmatch.

Changing the code the following...

```
 elseif ($depth >= $min_depth && preg_match('/\.([^\.]*$)/', $mask, $file)) {
```

throws up this error instead:

**Warning: basename() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/sites/n/nanohex.org/public_html/includes/file.inc on line 905**

Line 905 looks like this:

$basename = basename($file);

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matches are in the array `$file`. You have to use the second entry in this array:

```
$basename = basename($file[1]);
```

But I guess your preg_match should be:

```
preg_match('/\.([^\.]*$)/', $file)
```

and then:

```
$basename = basename($file);
```

is OK.

[preg_match doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match.php)